# How can I receive YouTube notifications again?

Tags: youtube, account-management, notifications

I was an active user on YouTube, and YouTube was sending me emails when somebody was posting a new comment or uploading a new video (where I was subscribed). Then, for about four months, I was inactive and a few weeks ago YouTube stopped sending me email notifications.

I verified the [email settings page](http://www.youtube.com/account_notifications) where all checkboxes (from Email Notifications section) are checked:

[image: screen shot]

How can I receive YouTube notifications again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct answer. I use two email addresses for my YouTube account: `first@yahoo.com` and `second@gmail.com`. I use Yahoo, not Gmail, and my Gmail messages are redirected to my Yahoo email address.

Yesterday, I checked my Gmail account and I found **256 messages** in the Spam folder!

This was my problem: they weren't redirected to my Yahoo email address.

Hope that this will help future users who have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the last major update on YouTube, the message notification doesn't appear in the main page—I don't know if this a bug or something.
Anyway, you can check your inbox messages by going to YouTube settings and select inbox tab from the bar in top of the page.

Update:

You can get the notifications in your Gmail account.

Comment: I know that I can see my messages. I do this viewing my Inbox message, but what about **new** subscribers?

Comment: i searched for a lot to fix it, and i didn't find anything useful, finally i set the setting to notified me by emailing me on my gmail.

Comment: Is possible to be notified on gmail? If yes, edit your answer. If I can to do this, I will mark your answer and I will give you 50 rep.

Comment: i just update the answer, hope it's helped you.

Comment: It would be great if you add few steps how can I set this.

Comment: @John you must connect your gmail to your youtube account, then go to your youtube account to set what do you want to notified at. and make sure your gmail account is connected to youtube otherwise you can't get emails.

Comment: @Ibrahom Swaiss, add the steps how can I connect it. I have a gmail account on Youtube.

Comment: @John i posted another answer, how to connect your youtube account.

Answer (score 0):

open your youtube account and sign-in with your id and password now follow following steps

Please visit http://www.youtube.com/finish_link_upgra…

Next, follow the instructions below:

Do you see a message that says "Please link your YouTube and Google accounts?"

If Yes, then confirm whether you want to link the two Accounts listed, or choose whether you want to link to another different Google Account.

If No:
If you want to link your YouTube account with a NEW Google Account, then enter your email address & new password on the right hand side of the page.

If you want to link your YouTube account with an EXISTING Google Account, then click "sign in here" and sign in with the Google Account you want to link to.

Comment: I got this message: "Your account is already linked to a Google Account"

Comment: @John great, then everything ok, just open your youtube account, you'll find at the top right your account image, click on it, then click on "youtube settings", the at the right you'll find "Email" option, then set what do you want to get notified at.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has disabled email notifications for new videos. You can see the announcement here: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/63269933/changes-to-emails-you-receive-for-new-video-uploads-from-your-subscriptions?hl=en

However YouTube channels do have RSS feeds so you can post the channel URL (for example https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLA_DiR1FfKNvjuUpBHmylQ) into your favourite RSS reader.

If you prefer to receive emails there are various RSS readers that send email.

- https://feedmail.org - Free trial or paid. Real-time updates.
- https://blogtrottr.com - Free with ads or paid.
- https://feedrabbit.com/ - Free for a limited number of feeds or paid.